# Anchor tag is not clickable

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,30);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("(//a[contains(text(),'Download')])")));   
WebElement download = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//a[contains(text(),'Download')])"));
download.click();
```

I am trying to click a download link in a chrome via selenium. It has many other links in the page and those are working but this download link alone causes `timeout exception`.

And the anchor tag in the page is as follows

```
<a href="https://www.somexyz.com/key/url?url=http%3A//www.somexyz.net/webform_protected_file/lwhW0167ec9HZBEefQrIoSg6JpnW0zvlQyxL-iaR8Ms/download" target="_other" rel="nofollow">Download file</a>
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Are there more elements with `Download` text? is it inside `iframe`?

Comment: Does the url inside the anchor tag give an answer?

Comment: Please check the link is inside iframe? if yes, then switch to the frame before click on it.

Comment: Thanks guys. Yes the link was in the iframe, so need to switch to that frame and then had to click the link.

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.switchTo().frame("msg_body");
                WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,30);
                wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("(//a[contains(text(),'Download')])")));   
                WebElement download = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//a[contains(text(),'Download')])")); 
                download.click();
```

The above code worked for me with first switching the driver to the iframe that is intended and then selecting the link worked.